# How can I get CMake to "forget" about a target?

Tags: cmake, build-dependencies, buildconfiguration, build-target

My CMake project has several dependencies. One of the dependencies may define a target named `some_target`, and may not define it. Another one of my dependencies performs certain configuration actions based on whether or not `some_target` was defined:

```
if (TARGET some_target)
    # do stuff
endif()
```

I can't control my dependency's CMake code, but I do want to prevent those actions from being taken, for reasons. And - I don't need some_target in my project.

My question: How can I make CMake "forget" about the `some_target` target?

Comment: I do not think so. It sounds like adding the target should be protected with an `option()`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: The adding of this target is not done by me, so I can't control that.